# How can I change the default shell Project.el uses?

Tags: project

I use Emacs’ builtin project management and really like it, but am also a vterm user and would like this to be the shell that opens when I run `project-shell`. Is there a way to set this, or else would someone be able to provide an alternative bit of elisp that will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Not without editing the source. If you look at the definition of `project-shell` in project.el you will see that it calls the `shell` function. The `shell` function starts shells, not vterms. If you look a few lines down you will find the `project-eshell` function, which calls `eshell` instead. `eshell` doesn’t start vterms either, but you should be able to recognize the pattern

Perhaps you should write a `project-vterm` function and add it to your init file. Make it call `vterm` for you, with the working directory set to the root directory of the project that the current buffer is in (you’ll see that the other two functions call `(project-root (current-project t))` to find out what that directory is, so presumably you would do the same).

Once you’ve done that, consider sending it off to the emacs-devel mailing list as an enhancement to be included in future releases.